# Catching error caused by InitialContext.lookup

Tags: java, error-handling, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I'm developing a command line client (Java SE6) that now needs to talk to a Glassfish 2.1 server.
The code for setting up this connection is

```
try {
    final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    final String ejbName = GeneratorCancelledRemote.class.getName();
    generatorCancelled = (GeneratorCancelledRemote) context.lookup(ejbName);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    System.err.println("--> Could not call server:");
    t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    runWithOutEJB = true;
}
```

I'm now testing it without a running server and the client (when run from Eclipse 4.2) just bombs with

```
31.10.2012 10:40:09 com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl 
WARNUNG: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2783)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2804)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:130)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:192)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:328)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:112)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.narrowProvider(SerialContext.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.getCachedProvider(SerialContext.java:259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:409)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.werkii.latex.generator.Generator.main(Generator.java:344)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:347)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:244)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:532)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:105)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:332)
    ... 15 more
```

It's o.k. for now (while I'm still in development) that it bombs, but it does this repeatedly and the `catch` clause is never reached (even though I'm catching `Throwable`) - the message is not printed.

So how can I handle connection errors during `lookup` in my program?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking to an EJB outside your JVM, you might want to provide additional details to the initial context. For Glassfish, try

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(“java.naming.factory.initial”, “com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory”);
props.setProperty(“java.naming.factory.url.pkgs”, “com.sun.enterprise.naming”);
props.setProperty(“java.naming.factory.state”, “com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl”);
props.setProperty(“org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost”, “127.0.0.1″);
props.setProperty(“org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort”, “3700″);
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext (props);
```

Comment: I know I need this - but how do I catch errors when things go wrong?

Comment: I guess you are already catching the error with your catch block. Quick suggestion off the question - you would want to avoid blanket exceptions as in `catch (Throwable t)` and catch specific exceptions and handle them accordingly.

Comment: I _know_ that `Throwable` is bad style. I tried with `Exception`, but it wasn't catched. And I'm pretty sure that the `catch` is not reached even now.

Comment: Interesting. I see the trace has no errors but only exceptions. So, `catch (Exception)` should handle it. Could you try commenting out `t.printStackTrace(System.err);` and check whether the trace is getting printed. Also, is `Could not call server:` getting printed in your client log?

Comment: This (passing properties to the constructor of `InitialConext`) is actually _wrong_ for Glassfish: see the [FAQ](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB).

Comment: The properties in the FAQ looks like the one which is mentioned above. Am I missing something?

Comment: The sentence in the FAQ: "The most common problem developers run into is passing specific JNDI bootstrapping properties to InitialContext(args).  Some other vendors require this step but GlassFish does not.   Instead, use the no-arg InitialContext() constructor."